# XPath select specific child elements

Tags: c#, xpath

If I have XML tree like this-

```
<Parent>
 <Image Name="a"/>
 <Image Name="b"/>
 <Child>
  <Image Name="c"/>
  <Image Name="d"/>
 </Child>
 <SomeElem>
  <Image Name="h"/>
  <Image Name="g"/>
 </SomeElem>
 <Image Name="e"/>
</Parent>
```

I want to select all `<Image\>` nodes except those listed inside `<Child\>` node.
Currently I am using query to select all Image nodes, -

```
xElement.XPathSelectElements("//ns:Image", namespace);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get all `Image` elements, whose parent is not a `Child`.

`//*[not(self::Child)]/Image`

Edit 1:
*This one below won't work as `Parent` is also selected in the process, which is not a `Child`, and Image is one of the descendants (through `Child`).*

<strike>you could also get all `Image` elements, whose ancestor is not a `Child`</strike>

`//*[not(self::Child)]//Image`

Edit 2:
This probably works best for all cases. It gets all `Image` nodes who are not descendants of `Child`.

`//Image[not(ancestor::Child)]`

Comment: No, its still not working :( with //Image[not(ancestor::Child)]
or with xElement.XPathSelectElements("//*[not(self::Child)]//ns:Image", namespace)

Comment: the xpath looks correct, here's an online tool you could use for testing - http://www.mizar.dk/XPath/Default.aspx. Is xElement pointing to a correct node?

Comment: Hey Anurag, yes //Image[not(ancestor::Child)] this is working fine on ur link as well as in my code :)  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to select those at the root level, then you can just do:

```
xElement.XPathSelectElements("/ns:Image", namespace);
```

The `//` tells the xpath engine to look at all `Image` nodes, no matter their depth.

Comment: No I want all the child Image elements no matter if its root level or child's child.

Comment: Although I could change my answer to match your edits, @Anurag's answer already addresses that case.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kaleb. Sorry, but I had to edit my question as it was confusing and not precise.

Comment: No problem. I was being sufficiently lazy not to answer what I thought you may have intended ;).

Comment: lol..but anyways you sufficiently answered what my question implied ;)

Answer (score 0):

`/ns:Parent/ns:Image` should do the trick

Comment: The Image element can be anywhere in the xml. Parent/Image, Parent/ABCD/Image, Parent/../../Image.
I want all those Image elements except inside Child i.e. Parent/Child.